A deceptively simple regularity problem for functions on the plane
By various meanderings and toying with simpler problems, my current research has lead me to the following quite straightforward question, which I am wholly unable to answer:
Consider a twice differentiable function on the plane, let us call it $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.
We assume that $f(x,y)=0$ whenever $x\le0$, and we consider the following quantity:
$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|\frac{1}{x}\;dx\;dy.$$
We ask, inspired by Sobolev regularity, if there exists a constant $C>0$ such that the following bound always holds:
$$I \le C \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right| + \left|\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}\right| + \left|\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right| \;dxdy.$$
I am completely unable to prove, nor disprove, this statement despite considerable effort! Any external interest or input would be most helpful.

Would you consider changing your title to describe the content of the problem, rather than your evaluation of its difficulty?  I think that the latter goes in the post itself (or is probably better omitted), whereas your current title doesn't provide much of a guide to tell a reader whether they'll be interested.

@LSpice The title is exactly the thing that would interest me!
